# Retrieve the ID of the getUser using JWT

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, jwt

When I make a request on Postman to retrieve the user's ID, I get a response of -1.

I am able to register new data into the database.
I can also connect with a created account and login.

However, I am unable to make modifications due to an error, and I am unable to retrieve the ID.

Thank you in advance for any help and responses.

// jwt.utilse.js

```
module.exports = {
  generateTokenForUser: function (userData) {
    return jwt.sign(
      {
        userId: userData.id,
        isAdmin: userData.isAdmin,
      },
      JWT_SING_SECRET,
      {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      }
    );
  },
  parseAuthorization: function (authorization) {
    return authorization != null ? authorization.replace("Bearer ", "") : null;
  },
  getUserId: function (authorization) {
    let userId = -1;
    let token = module.exports.parseAuthorization(authorization);
    if (token != null) {
      try {
        let jwtToken = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SING_SECRET);
        if (jwtToken != null) userId = jwtToken.userId;
      } catch (err) {}
    }
    return userId;
  },
};
```

// usersCrtl.js

```
 getUserProfile: function (req, res) {
        let headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
        let userId = jwtUtils.getUserId(headerAuth);

        if (userId < 0) return res.status(400).json({
            error: "wrong token"
        });

        models.User.findOne({
                attributes: ["id", "email", "username", "bio"],
                where: {
                    id: userId
                },
            })
            .then(function (user) {
                if (user) {
                    res.status(201).json(user);
                } else {
                    res.status(404).json({
                        error: "user not found"
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: "cannot fetch user"
                });
            });
    },
    updateUserProfile: function (req, res) {
        let headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
        let userId = jwtUtils.getUserId(headerAuth);

        let bio = req.body.bio;
        if (userId < 0) return res.status(400).json({
            error: userId
        });

        asyncLib.waterfall(
            [
                function (done) {
                    models.User.findOne({
                            attributes: ["id", "bio"],
                            where: {
                                id: userId
                            },
                        })
                        .then(function (userFound) {
                            done(null, userFound);
                        })
                        .catch(function (err) {
                            res.status(500).json({
                                error: "unable to verify user"
                            });
                        });
                },
                function (userFound, done) {
                    if (userFound) {
                        userFound
                            .update({
                                bio: bio ? bio : userFound.bio,
                            })
                            .then(function (userFound, done) {
                                done(userFound);
                            })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                                res.status(500).json({
                                    error: "cannot update user"
                                });
                            });
                    } else {
                        res.status(404).json({
                            error: "user not found"
                        });
                    }
                },
            ],
            function (userFound) {
                if (userFound) {
                    return res.status(201).json(userFound);
                } else {
                    return res.status(500).json({
                        error: "cannot update user profile"
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    },
```

Comment: You wrote code specifically for catching and then ignoring errors. Remove that and find out what the real problem is.

Comment: I don't understand why returning the userId's ID:

returns: -1
let headerAuth = req.headers["authorization"];
let userId = jwtUtils.getUserId(headerAuth);

the functions "updateUserProfile" and "getUserProfile" have the same instruction."

(Note: I assumed "instruction" refers to the same code instruction being used in both functions.)

Comment: Your code will return -1 if an error happened, and you wrote your code so you won't see the error and just ignore it. Remove the try..catch block for another clue. Never just ignore errors like this.

Comment: Thank you, I am still a beginner. It is not yet very clear to me how to perform tests and retrieve results.

Comment: Not sure if JWT is the best place to start learning. You might get up and running faster and with fewer security bugs if you use sessions. But if you are going to keep trying this, let me know what error you got after removing the try...catch block.

Comment: General advice i would give is don't use `try...catch` at all unless you have a specific purpose for it. It's better usually to see the error .

Comment: Thank you, my error comes from the getUserId function (jwt.utils.js) when it is called by the updateUserProfile function (usersCtrl.js). It returns -1. But when I call the getUserProfile function (usersCtrl.js), I correctly receive the ID. The token is properly decrypted

Comment: Jacques please follow my advice first and if you *didn't* get an error, lets look at some other potential issues. We _need_ to know if there was an error. It's the only place `-1` can potentially be set, and it's certainly possible for functions to error sometimes but not always because there's several external things that modify what the function does.

Comment: I am running tests. Upon console.log() output, I was able to capture the token verification and ID value, but only with the getUserProfile function. When the function is called with the updateUserProfile function, it doesn't work.

Comment: have you removed the try...catch block or did you ignore that part?

Comment: Yes, I have removed the 'if' and 'try' instructions. I can connect and retrieve the user's information without any issues for authentication and verification. However, I still have difficulty updating the bio because I cannot retrieve the ID.

Comment: Ok great! If you didn't get any new errors or crashes, then you elimated 1 (really important) case where this might happen. The other 2 cases where this may happen in your code is if `jwtToken` is `null` or if `token` is `null`. Can you find out which one it is?

Comment: Yes, I have tested it. console.log(token != null) and (jwtToken != null). If the request is made by the login function and getUserProfile = true. BUT, for updateUserProfile, I don't have any response. Nothing at all, no error or not undefined.

Comment: @Event It's as if the updateUserProfile instruction doesn't reach getUserId. Yet it is the same module.exports used by getUserProfile. That's what I don't understand. The getUserProfile and updateUserProfile functions use the same instruction to get and post the data, the headerAuth and userId variables. Shouldn't the instruction reach >getUserId> in the same way?

Comment: @Event Hello, I allow myself to ask for your help again. I didn't give up. I looked for a solution after you asked me to do tests with the console. I got "true" as output except for `updateUserProfile()`, for which I didn't get any feedback at all.

Comment: I think at this point, it might be worthwhile using the browser's debugger and setting a breakpoint in `updateUserProfile` so you can see exactly step-by-step what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do it as quickly as possible. I don't understand this one, but I think I have done everything correctly